# Solr8- stored=false fields show up in the response

Tags: solr, solr8

I have fields that set up as "stored=false", still they are showing up in the response. I checked  "useDocValuesAsStored" is set to false. Any idea why these fields showing up in the response.

Comment: What kind of fields? i.e. how are the fields defined? Did you index any content into the fields before changing the definition? Also be aware that `useDocValuesAsStored` only refers to wildcard field queries, and not when the fields are specifically requested (_When `useDocValuesAsStored="false"`, non-stored DocValues fields can still be explicitly requested by name in the fl param, but will not match glob patterns (`"*"`)._)

Comment: It's simple string field-> field name="domainNames" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true". I had the field definition as stored=true when I was testing. Then I changed and deleted the data directories. Restarted server. Also I did clean before doing dataimport. Did not specifically ask for field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new in solr but when I checked the schema.xml file, I saw that, all *fieldTypes* are almost DocValues (docValues="true")

```
<fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>
<fieldType name="pints" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
<fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true"/>
<fieldType name="plongs" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

you can check it in *Schema in Admin UI*. so set docValues to false if you dont want to retrive in result set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Setting docValues="false" worked.